# How to prevent DBeaver JBDC Informix connection from appending client IP to user

Tags: informix, dbeaver

Recently setup a connection to an Informix database from Dbeaver (JDBC) but getting error:

***Incorrect password or user com.informix.asf.IfxASFRemoteException: testuser@xxx.xx.xx.xx is not known on the database server.***

It appears that user account I'm testing with gets the IP address appended to it in the connection string which won't match the user in the Informix database.

I've tested an ODBC connection using the credentials I was given to test with, and they work so seems it's a configuration issue for my Informix connection.

Anyone know how to disable the feature that appends the IP address to the user in the connection?

Comment: Found I can embed the user/password and make it work but not ideal

Comment: Ummm, not sure that's accurate. The driver (doesn't matter which one) will send just the UID to the server, the server will validate it and, if the auth failed (unkown user, wrong password, not trusted, etc)  it will  throw a 951 error "incorrect password or user" and then it will include a '@xxxxxx' suffix in the error message to let you know where the connection came from.

Comment: @jsagrera  thanks for your response.  I'll continue to test but finding that if I embed the user/password in the URL string my connection works but if I put in the user/password in the authentication UI I get that error so that's why I thought additional info was being passed

Comment: If you force the wrong user or password from the ODBC connection (or even the JDBC conn string) the error on the engine side should have the "'@xxxxxx".
Maybe when using the UI, the password is not properly passed to the JDBC driver and that's why you get the 951.